# html2pdf margin border for all pages

Tags: php, html2pdf

I am using **html2pdf** for **converting my html page to pdf**. It is working Properly. I am using margin and background image for all pages. It is also working. I need margin borders on top,left,right and bottom for all pages. How can I do that.

```
<page backtop="7mm" backbottom="7mm" backleft="10mm" backright="10mm" backimg="http://test.com/img/watermark.png"> 
    <page_header> 
        <img src="http://test.com/img/logo.png" width="100">
    </page_header>
    <page_footer> 
                <img src="http://test.com/img/logo.png" width="100">
 [[page_cu]]/[[page_nb]]
    </page_footer>
<div style="text-align:center;font-size:18px;">test</div>
<table style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:30px;">
<tr><td>content</td><tr>
</table>
</page>
```